# How to make a transparent window in xlib?

Tags: x11

I have gone through a of information online on how to make a transparent window in xlib. My goal is to have a Imlib2 image displayed with a transparent background. I have an image with the transparent background, and now you can only see the window background color. I want to make that color transparent so things behind the window can be seen, the the image is still displayed.

I have the following code:

```
XVisualInfo vinfo;
XMatchVisualInfo(DISPLAY, DefaultScreen(DISPLAY), 32, TrueColor, &vinfo);

XSetWindowAttributes attr;
attr.background_pixel = 0;
attr.border_pixel = 0;
attr.colormap = XCreateColormap(DISPLAY, ROOT, vinfo.visual, AllocNone);

window = XCreateWindow(
    DISPLAY,
    parent_window,
    0,
    0,
    button_geometry.width,
    button_geometry.height,
    0,
    32,
    InputOutput,
    vinfo.visual,
    CWBackPixmap | CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel,
    &attr
);
XSelectInput(DISPLAY, window, StructureNotifyMask);
XMapWindow(DISPLAY, window);
XSync(DISPLAY, false);
```

This does create a window and I can interact with it (as in it has click, release, and motion events), but I cannot see it at all. How can I only have my background color be transparent so I can still see the xlib image.